# Change div class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have that code:

```
<ul class="top_menu dl-menu menu">
<li data-id="id123" class="megactive"><a href="/avis">Produits</a>

<ul class="dl-submenu">
    <li><a href="/huile">&Agrave; base d&#39;huile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/comprimes">Comprim&eacute;s</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training-booster">Bruleur de graisses/Protection du foie</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Packs</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/apropos">Qui sommes-nous</a></li>
<li><a href="/comment-utiliser">Mode d&#39;utilisation</a>
<ul class="dl-submenu">
    <li><a href="/huile">&Agrave; base d&#39;huile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/comprimes">Comprim&eacute;s</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training-booster">Bruleur de graisses/Protection du foie</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Packs</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

```
<div class="megamenu" id="id123">
```

And i have problems when i try to apply some css to class megamenu when class megactive his on over.

So i want when .megactive:hover change .megamenu css.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _And i have problems when i try to apply some css to class megamenu when class megactive his on over._ - And the problem is.....? And where's your jQuery code?

Comment: at a guess based on your limited info, sounds like your looking for the `:hover` pseudo selector.  That being said, I voted to close the question until a minimal, complete, and verifiable example is posted.

Comment: So i want when .megactive:hover change .megamenu css.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to toggle a class on hover, take a look at this. Added the functionality of hovering over the OTHER element with the megactive class, and having that change the CSS on the megamenu-classed element.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(".megamenu").hover( function(){
  $(this).addClass("megactive");
}, function (){
  $(this).removeClass("megactive")
});

$(".megactive").hover( function(){
  $(".megamenu").addClass("doTheOverThing");
  // And maybe do a manual CSS change...
  $(".megamenu").css("border", "1px dotted blue");
 }, function(){
  $(".megamenu").removeClass("doTheOverThing");
  $(".megamenu").css("border", "inherit");
 });
```

```css
.megactive {
  background-color: #cc9;
}

.doTheOverThing {
  background-color: #99c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top_menu dl-menu menu">
<li data-id="id123" class="megactive"><a href="/avis">Produits</a>

<ul class="dl-submenu">
    <li><a href="/huile">&Agrave; base d&#39;huile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/comprimes">Comprim&eacute;s</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training-booster">Bruleur de graisses/Protection du foie</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Packs</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/apropos">Qui sommes-nous</a></li>
<li><a href="/comment-utiliser">Mode d&#39;utilisation</a>
<ul class="dl-submenu">
    <li><a href="/huile">&Agrave; base d&#39;huile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/comprimes">Comprim&eacute;s</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training-booster">Bruleur de graisses/Protection du foie</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Packs</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<div class="megamenu" id="id123">
Foo
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(".megamenu").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```